# If statement use in calling onActivityResult()

Tags: android

I am curious to know the difference between the following two methods. Does it matter which one I use, or can they be used according to preference?

Here is the first example:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_DATA){
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Here is the second one:

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_DATA){
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: These two snippets are identical in function, however the first one suggests you may add other error logging before returning when `resultCode` is not `Activity.RESULT_OK`, or that you may wish to do other handling when it is not `REQUEST_DATA`. If you are genuinely only interested in doing something when the result is OK and is `REQUEST_DATA` then there is no difference whatsoever. Choose based on whichever fits your current coding standards/existing codebase.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I'm a new user on this site that would like to participate and learn programming just like anyone else. I'm trying to get some reputation, but then I only get downvotes? Really discouraging.

Comment: Normally it would be polite for somebody to leave feedback on why they are downvoting you. In this case I'm not actually sure I can see a good reason for it to be downvoted like it has. It's a very simple question, which some people mistake for low-effort or "too obvious shouldn't be asked" - but imo this asked a very specific question which can be shown to have a single technically correct answer (not opinion based). I imagine the main reason is that it doesn't transfer well to future readers - it's unlikely anybody will ever have the same specific question, which a lot of people view as bad.

Comment: Thanks Bilkokuya, I appreciate your reply. That is a very sensible explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically both statements are identical.

The second statement makes the code more readable and understandable, so I always prefer the same. But the condition statement is too complex then nested if is more preferable. Anyway it depends on the coding standard that you follow.